# setAttribute() of Javascript not reverting to original state with values

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a trello-like list chrome extension and I use javascript to instance the list and delete them. I also try to make the container of the list's height and **top** of button that adds the list. However, when I delete the lists, the size does not ever back to the amount that is put into Javascript. What should I do?

Edit: if the run is working wonky I am sorry I am using different font files and I don't know how to import them

```js
var listnum = 0;
var butadd = 250;
var numadd = 360; 

var started = false;

var id_arr = []

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' ,addList, false);

function addList()
{
    var btn = document.getElementById('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function()
    {   

        if (started == false){
            started = true;
        }

        var new_list = document.createElement('DIV');
        new_list.className = "list";
        var newlistid = String('newList' + listnum);
        new_list.id = newlistid;

        var delete_list = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        delete_list.className = "delList";
        delete_list.id = 'deletebutton';

        delete_list.onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('Lcontainer').removeChild(this.parentNode);
            listnum--;
            if (listnum > 5){
                numadd -= 65;
                butadd -= 65;
                document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", 'height: '+numadd+'px');
                document.getElementById('button').setAttribute("style", "top:"+ butadd + 'px');
                
            }
    };
        
        id_arr.push(listnum);
        changeatt();

        document.getElementById('Lcontainer').appendChild(new_list);
        document.getElementById(newlistid).appendChild(delete_list);
    }, false);
}

function changeatt(){
    listnum++;
    if (listnum >= 5){
        document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", 'height: '+numadd+'px');
        document.getElementById('button').setAttribute("style", "top:"+ butadd + 'px');
        numadd += 65;
        butadd += 65;
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 17%);

    width: 300px;
    height: 420px;
}


@font-face{
    font-family: 'SIMPLIFICA';
    src: url("Fonts/SIMPLIFICA Typeface/SIMPLIFICA Typeface.ttf") format('woff')
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'Blogger';
    src: url("Fonts/Blogger/TTF/BloggerSans.ttf")
}

h1{
    font-family: Blogger;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.logo{
    color:deeppink;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    left: 5px;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


.by{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Blogger;
    font: "Blogger Sans-Light.otf";
    font-style: bolder;
    color: darkgray;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: -85px;
    left: 100px;
    float: left;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* logo*/ 

.Minim{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Blogger;
    font-style: bolder;
    font-size: 40px;
    font: "Blogger Sans-Light.otf";
    top: -120px;
    float: left;
    left: 110px;
    color:white;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* list container*/
.container{
    display: block;
    position: relative; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 22%);
    border-radius: 25px;
    top: -30px;
}

/* list do not delete*/
.list{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 280px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 65%);
    border-radius: 25px;
    float:left;
    left:-38px;
    top: -140px;
    padding: 1%;
    gap: 10%;
    margin: 5px;
    
    font-family: Blogger;
    font-style: bolder;
    color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
    text-align: left; 
    
    transition: .1s;
}  

.list:hover{transform: scale(1.01);}

/*delete button */

.delList{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    width:25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
    border:none;
    background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
    opacity: 0.5;
    float: right;
    right: 20px;
    top: 10px;

    color:rgb(99, 99, 99);
    background-image: linear-gradient(deeppink, deeppink);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 0% 100%;

    transition: background-size .3s, color.3s;
}

.delList:hover{
    background-size:100% 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

/*add button*/

.addlist{
    width:300px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 190px;
    float:left;
    left:-38px;

    background-color:rgb(223, 223, 223);
    border-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
    border:1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    outline: none;
    border:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: SIMPLIFICA;
    font-size: 30px;

    transition: .1s;
}

.addlist:hover{transform: scale(1.03);}

/*congratulating users */
.noassignment{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 65%);
    font-family: Blogger;
    opacity: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 50px;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Esse</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script> 
        <h1 class="logo">Esse</h1>
        <p class="by">by</p> 
        <p class = "Minim">Minim</p>
        <div class="container" id="container">
            <p class="noassignment">No assignments WooHoo!</p> 
            <ul class="hwcontainer" id="Lcontainer">
                <li><input type="button" id="button" value="+" class="addlist" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `.setAttribute()` on the `.style` element is not a good idea. You should access the `style` object from the DOM node and update its properties directly.

Comment: @Pointy How should I do that?

Comment: Get the element and set properties on the `.style` object directly

Comment: I don't know how exactly to do that... @Pointy do you have any examples?

Comment: `document.getElementById("x").style.display = "block"` or whatever, this is extremely basic DOM manipulation stuff. There are countless tutorials online that explain how this stuff works.